# Apache Camel NotifyBuilder not working as expected

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to test an error handling route. The `NotificationBuilder` does not work as expected (it always returns false).

Created a main route and a test route to test the main route. I used Spring Boot - all other tests work fine, so there is no problem with the setup I guess.

```
errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("seda:errorQueue").maximumRedeliveries(5).redeliveryDelay(1000));

from("file://{{inputFolder}}?delay=10s&noop=true")
.routeId("InputFolderToTestSedaRoute")
.setHeader("myHeader", constant("MY_HEADER_CONSTANT_VALUE"))
.to("seda://testSeda")
.log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "**** Input File Pushed To Output Folder *****");
```

There is an error route too.

```
from("seda:errorQueue")
.routeId("ErrorHandlingRoute")
.log("***** error body: ${body} *****")
.log("***** Exception Caught: ${exception} *****");
```

I then used `adviceWith()` to throw an Exception in the main route.

Then created the NotifyBuilder.

```
NotifyBuilder errorRouteNotifier = new NotifyBuilder(camelContext)
                   // .wereSentTo("seda:errorQueue")
                    .fromRoute("ErrorHandlingRoute*")
                    .whenReceived(1)
                    .create();
```

Then I sent message using `ProducerTemplate`. But when I test the match condition, it always fails.

```
boolean done = errorRouteNotifier.matches(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
assertTrue("Should have thrown Exception and caught at errorQueue", done);
```

But the message is routed to the `ErrorHandlingRoute` as I can see the messages (body and exception) I asked to print there.

Please let me know what is the issue here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What Camel version do you use

Comment: Claus, we use camel 2.23.2 and spring boot 2.1.3.RELEASE. Thanks

Comment: The source code with test is uploaded to https://github.com/sreejeshraj/camel-spring-boot-sample. The test for NotificationBuilder is in the test method testExceptionInInputFolderToTestSedaRoute()

Comment: Thanks can you try with 2.24.1 also, and if its still a problem, then log a JIRA and point to this github source code so we can take a look later. Also add a bit instructions in the github with a readme file etc.

Comment: Thanks Claus, tried with 2.24.1. Still no luck. Will update the Github and will log a JIRA ticket later today.

Comment: JIRA ticket CAMEL-13687 is created, thanks Claus.